# Calculadora AndroiStudio

Tags: java, android

Boa noite
Estou a criar uma aplicação utilizando 5 "caixas" (`EditText`) em que podesse multiplicar as caixas que quisesse.

Exemplo: valorodd1 * valorodd2= resu.... valorodd1*valorodd2*valorodd3=resu....valorodd1*valorodd2*va‌​loodd3*valorodd4=res‌​u....valorodd1*valor‌​odd2*valoodd3*valoro‌​dd4*valorodd5=resu

Como na seguinte imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código:

```
public void somar (View v){

        EditText odd1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText7);
        String stringodd1 = odd1.getText().toString();

        EditText odd2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText8);
        String stringodd2 = odd2.getText().toString();


        EditText montante = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText12);
        String stringmontante = montante.getText().toString();


        NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");

        if (stringodd1.trim().isEmpty() || stringodd2.trim().isEmpty()|| stringmontante.trim().isEmpty() )
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Campos em branco",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else
        {

            double valorodd1 = Double.parseDouble(stringodd1);
            double valorodd2 = Double.parseDouble(stringodd2);
            double valormontante = Double.parseDouble(stringmontante);


            double resu = valorodd1 * valorodd2 * valormontante;


            TextView resultado = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView15);
            resultado.setText (formatter.format(resu) + "€" );
```

Comment: Qual a questão que tem ou dificuldade que está a encontrar? Aproveite e acrescente o código que está a utilizar na aplicação que foca o sua duvida/dificuldade.

Comment: Tenho este código com uma simples soma na caixa 1 e 2. O meu objetivo é poder calcular a caixa 1 x 2 = total, ou caixa 1 x 2 x 3 = total ou caixa 1 x 6 = total.   Obrigado

Comment: Você tem algum botão que quando clica ele faz as operações ?

Comment: Fazer N multiplicações sucessivas ? E iam ser postas onde ? Existem N `TextViews` para esses resultados ?

Comment: Sim, como mostra no meu código acima tenho o botão para calcular as multiplicações. O erro no meu código é que tenho 6 Edittext para introduzir 1 número e 1 textview para apresentar o resultado, quando eu quero multiplicar 2 números não dá, pois sou obrigado a preencher as restantes "caixas" com números para fazer a multiplicação e eu quero poder utilizar a "caixas" que quiser. Se eu quiser multiplicar 2 número meto um número numa caixa e outro numero na outra caixa, se eu quiser multiplicar 3 meto pelo mesmo 1 numero em cada caixa e multiplico. Espero que tenham entendido. Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

O melhor para o que pretende seria mesmo utilizar um `array` para os `EditText` e um ciclo/laço para os percorrer e efetuar as multiplicações caso contenham valores.

Seguindo essa ideia, ficaria assim:

```
public void somar (View v){

    //cria um array com os edits todos
    EditText[] edits = new EditText[] {
        (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText7),
        (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText8),
        (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText9),
        (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText10),
        (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText11),
        (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText12) //12 é o montante
    }

    TextView textResultado = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView15);

    double resultado = 1;
    boolean algumPreenchido = false;

    //aqui percorre agora todos os edits, sejam eles quantos forem
    for (int i = 0; i < edits.length; ++i){

        //aqui vê se o edit foi preenchido, e só multiplica se tiver valor
        if (!edits[i].getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()){
            resultado *= Double.parseDouble(edits[i].getText().toString());
            algumPreenchido = true;
        }
    }

    NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");

    //Mostra o resultado caso tenha sido considerado algum valor, ou 0 caso contrário
    textResultado.setText (formatter.format(algumPreenchido ? resu : 0) + "€" );
}
```

Note que o programa irá falhar no calculo se algum dos `EditText` tiver valores preenchidos que não sejam números. Nessa situação terá que adicionar captura de exceções com `try` `catch` e dar o tratamento que considera apropriado.